# Auto increment in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying create a table with auto increment in Oracle SQL. I have the following SQL code:

```
DROP TABLE "Account" CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
CREATE TABLE "Account" (
  "Id" NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
  "Name" VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
  "User" VARCHAR2(16) NOT NULL,
  "Email" VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
  "Password" VARCHAR2(16) NOT NULL,
  "Level" VARCHAR2(16) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "Account_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);

DROP SEQUENCE "Account_seq";
CREATE SEQUENCE "Account_seq" START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 10000;

INSERT INTO "Account" VALUES (Account_seq.NEXTVAL, 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'user');
INSERT INTO "Account" VALUES (Account_seq.NEXTVAL, 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'user');
```

Oracle SQL Developer says that Account_seq is created, but still it gives me an error: "sequence does not exist"...

Comment: why did you tag this sql server if it is about oracle.

Comment: Stackoverflow suggested it!

Comment: It suggested it as a tag that starts with the letters sql?

Comment: I would suggest writing your `insert` statements with explicit column names too, so you can tell which value maps to which column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use double quotes to create an object (and the object name is not all upper case), then you are forced to use double quotes everywhere you refer to it.

So in this case, this would work (notice the double quotes around `Account_seq`):

```
INSERT INTO "Account" VALUES ("Account_seq".NEXTVAL, 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'user');
```

That said, using double quotes everywhere is annoying. Instead, consider changing the sequence creation to avoid using double quotes:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Account_seq ...
```

... that way, you can refer to it without double quotes and the sequence name won't be case sensitive.

**EDIT**

To clarify the case sensitivity part a little bit:

When you double quote an identifier, then Oracle looks for that identifier with that exact casing.

On the other hand, if you don't use double quotes, it will look for the equivalent identifier all upper-cased.

Example:

- `"Account_seq"`: it will look for `Account_seq`
- `"AcCoUnT_SeQ"`: it will look for `AcCoUnT_SeQ`
- `Account_seq`: it will look for `ACCOUNT_SEQ`
- `AcCoUnT_SeQ`: it will look for `ACCOUNT_SEQ`

Comment: Yup.  And in my opinion, there's not usually a good reason to quote the strings like that.

Comment: Case sensitivity isn't the issue, because the case is the same.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - are you sure that is the case?

Comment: @Hogan . . . I'm reading the question and `"Account_seq"` and `Account_seq` have the same case a I read them.

Answer (score 0):

If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you must use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object. So your insert statements should be:

```
INSERT INTO "Account" VALUES ("Account_seq".NEXTVAL, 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'user');
INSERT INTO "Account" VALUES ("Account_seq".NEXTVAL, 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'user');
```